# Python map on a group

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, functional-programming

There is an array of strings in this format:

`r = [["Name - Version - Author - Message"],[..],..]`

I run the following code on this data structure:

```
from itertools import groupby

m = map(lambda x: x.split(" - ", 3), r)
group = groupby(m, lambda y: y[0]) # group by name
```

This works fine (output is grouped by name) but then running the following:

```
dot = re.compile('\.')
# "Names" have to be changed from first.last to first-last
output = map(lambda (n,g): (dot.sub('-', n), g), group)
```

This does the regex substitution correctly but it loses all the grouped data. Why? What's happening here? How do I fix this?

When I run this loop:

```
for name,grp in output:
    print list(grp)
```

It outputs an empty array for each `grp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Py2's `map` is eager, while the groups produced by `groupby` are lazy. As soon as you iterate to the next group from `groupby`, the previous group becomes invalid (the underlying iterator is advanced past it).

You have two options:

1. Use a lazy `map` function
2. Convert the group to a realized sequence as you iterate so it isn't lost

The former is easy:

```
from future_builtins import map
```

which gets you the Py3 version of `map` (which returns a lazy generator, not an eagerly filled sequence).

As is the latter, you just wrap `g` in the `list` (or if you prefer, `tuple`) constructor:

```
output = map(lambda (n,g): (dot.sub('-', n), list(g)), group)
```

Side-note: If you're using `map` with `lambda`s, it's going to be slower than just using the more Pythonic list comprehensions or generator expressions. If you need a `lambda` to use `map` (or `filter`), don't use `map`/`filter`, the listcomp or genexpr equivalent will always be faster.

So if you *really* need the speed, use C built-ins for the mapping functions when available, otherwise, use list comps or genexpr.

Example:

```
from future_builtins import map  # Generator based avoids temporary lists
from operator import itemgetter, methodcaller

m = map(methodcaller('split', " - ", 3), r)
# Or with genexpr:
m = (x.split(" - ", 3) for x in r)

group = groupby(m, itemgetter(0)) # group by name

# No good way to do this without lambda, so use listcomp or genexpr
output = [(dot.sub('-', n), list(g)) for n, g in group]
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes a lot of sense now. I wish that the docs mentioned that `map()` was eager. Also, I avoided the pythonic way so I can learn a bit of functional programming.

Comment: Python 2 itertools has `imap` which is equivalent to Python 3 map.

Comment: @stackErr List comprehensions were inspired by Haskell, so they happen to be Pythonic *and* functional.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Wow ok. Well I am just learning about map/reduce and some other basics. I guess list comprehensions will be next!

Comment: @stackErr: 1. [The docs do mention that `map` returns a `list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map); that implies eager (only returning an iterator/generator can make it lazy). 2. List comprehensions and generator expressions _are_ functional programming tools; they're borrowed from Haskell, a pure functional language. They combine the features of `map` and `filter` into a syntax feature; they're 100% functional programming tools.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: `future_builtins.map` is just aliasing `itertools.imap`. I just prefer to replace `map` entirely (I wrap it in `try:`/`except ImportError: pass` so the code works the same on Py2 and Py3), but yeah, if you want access to both lazy and eager mapping, you could use the `itertools` name.

Comment: @ShadowRanger so if lists are eager, why does wrapping `g` in a `list` work? Don't you need to wrap it a data structure that is lazy?

Comment: @stackErr: The problem is that `g` stops being valid the moment you get a new `g`. So wrapping in `list` eagerly acquires the contents while `g` is valid, before the next `g` is pulled (which would invalidate the previous `g`, but since we slurped it with `list`, there was nothing left in it anyway).